# Coldfusion - Install issue

Tags: apache-2.4, coldfusion

I can access my site fine from the server its on with the domain name, login in fine, etc. running Apache. But when I try from a remote machine on the same network it gives me the login in page, but after that I get the Forbidden message. Thoughts? Logs aren’t given me much…turned off firewall temporary to see if that was the issue.

I added the IP address to the server.xml thinking that would be the issue, but not luck.
address="x.x.x.x"

****Forbidden
You don’t have permission to access /page.cfm on this server.****

Comment: Any .htaccess file? There are some tips here for general access issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server